# Why is beta-minus decay considered isobaric?

Tags: radiation, physical-chemistry, radioactivity

Page 20 of *Physics in Nuclear Medicine* says that beta-minus decay is isobaric (eg the A/Z ratio remains the same). The reason it gives is that "mass number A does not change."

However, in beta-minus decay, the atomic number (Z) increases by 1. If A is constant and Z increases, then how is this an isobaric process?

Comment: An isobaric decay is a decay having A costant, not A/Z ratio.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Looks like I was just confused about that.

Answer (score 1):

Neutrons and protons are hadrons and are identified as an isotopic spin 1/2  hadron called [baryon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon). There are many hadrons, pions, kaons, detas, etc , and one of the quantum numbers that separates them is the baryon number. Protons and neutrons each have baryon number 1. Thus a neutron turning into a proton does not change the baryon number.

Isobaric means the same baryon number, counting baryons does not distinguish protons from neutrons.